problems with fseek and fread in C
I'm having an issue with fseek and fread. For some reason, using fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END); will not give me the end of my file, and instead go 1000 bytes farther, giving me junk data and generally being a pain...
I have checked, if I open the same file with python, f=open("filename","r"); print(len(f.read())) will give me the correct result, but using ftell() in C after the line I wrote previously will be 1000 off, and I have no idea why.
Here is the entire code for the function that is not working:
char* get_input(const char* path) {
    char* buffer = NULL;
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "r");

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        const long length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("%d\n", length);
        buffer = malloc(length+1);
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
            buffer[length+1] = '\0';
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    return buffer;
}

(it's just trying to read the contents of the file as a char array...)
The file I'm trying to open is just my day 2 input from advent of code(2024), that I copy-pasted to a text file as usual. I will not share it unless necessary as it is not good practice to do so.

You open a file that probably contains \n characters in text mode. Are you using Windows? Does your result change if you use "rb" to open the file in binary mode? Text files and ftell aren't best friends sometimes.

I am indeed on Windows. The text file does contains \n characters.
Exactly 1000 of them in fact
I have noticed that at some point, in debug view, my buffer contains \n\r instead of just \n, but not for the whole file length, and so I had junk data at the end
My code is otherwise able to handle \r\n and \n alike.
using "rb" made it somewhat better, although the size is still wrong (I think that's just the \rs tho), and I still have undesirable data at the end of the array (less of it, and the result now right)
The weirder part is, that code  has worked for a similar file.

" that code has worked for a similar file.". But that does not mean anything. The real issue is how this file has been created and what it actually contains. The fseek function will position the file to the physical end regardless of its content, so you need to look at what extra data has been written into it. Alternatively is is possible that someone has rewritten the file without correctly deleting all the previous content.

@Pauel3312 "using fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END); will not give me the end of my file" is incorrect.  fseek() did return a value corresponding to the end of the file.  The mistake is thinking this is the same as the length of the file when read in text mode.  Use the return value of fread() to determine how much was read.

"My code is otherwise able to handle \r\n and \n alike" -- if your code is intended to handle the file as a sequence of lines, with possibly non-native line terminators, then you must treat the input as binary, not text.  This is a matter of semantic correctness, not of how much better the otherwise-existing program's behavior may or may not be.

On the other hand, if the file is supposed to be a text file in the first place then a large part of the issue is that it does not conform to the text conventions of the system on which you're accessing it.

buffer[length+1] = '\0'; writes behind the buffer. Use index [length] instead.

With the help of the comments, I have found the two issues:
The first one was: I read my file as text when I should have read it as binary.
The second one was: I did not place my null terminator correctly.
The code I ended up using is:
char* get_input(const char* path) {
    char* buffer = NULL;
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "rb");

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        const long length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc(length+1);
        if (buffer)
        {
            size_t bytes = fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
            buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    return buffer;
}

